# A simple fundamental group of an hypersurface

Tags: complex-geometry, fundamental-group

Is there an example of analytic hypersurface in $C^n$ such that its fundamental group is simple i.e. does not have normal subgroups except the trivial group and the group itself ?

Thank you

EDIT : The fundamental of a hypersurface $A$ is by definition the group of its complement $\pi_1(C^n \setminus A)$.

Comment: The group with one element is simple (sorry for being pedantic).

Comment: Are you asking whether any specified finite simple group arises as the fundamental group of some analytic hypersurface?

Comment: The group may not necessarily be finite.

Comment: Are you asking for an example where the group is infinite and simple?

Comment: Actually I'm looking for an example where the group is simple ie such that the only normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself.

Comment: Okaaay . . . an affine hyperplane has trivial fundamental group so that the only normal subgroups are the trivial group and the group itself.

Comment: The group of an hyperplane is isomorphic to Z isn't it ? And Z is not simple !
(I define the fundamental group of an hypersurface A by $\pi_1(C^n \setminus A)$)

Comment: A hyperplane is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}^{n-1}$, which is simply connected.  Are you asking about the fundamental group of the *complement* of the hypersurface?

Comment: Sorry I didn't precise it above but yes. It is the group of its complement !
I hope my request is clear now...

Comment: Sorry for being pedantic :) 1: if "simple" means "has no normal subgroup", then no group is simple 2) according to all conventions, the group with 1 element is not simple (and 1 is not a prime number).

Comment: i modified my question. Is it absolutely clear for everyone now ? ;-)
Thank you very much

Comment: Can someone help me please ?